# Is "... become transformed into..." grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

There is a line in my biology book which uses *'become'* and *'transformed'* together. English is not my first language, just wanted to know if it's erroneous or not.

> So, if a recombinant DNA bearing gene for resistance to an antibiotic (e.g., ampicillin) is transferred into *E. coli* cells, the host cells **become transformed into** ampicillin-resistant cells.

Comment: It's fine. You could have ***are*** instead of ***become***, or skip the auxiliary verb altogether and just go with intransitive *the host cells **transform** into ampicillin-resistant cells*. All versions mean exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No I have never heard it said like that. A quick search showed results having "become transformed into" phrase, all from translation web sites. These results from translation web sites can be disregarded.

The correct sentences would be

- So, if a recombinant DNA bearing gene for resistance to an antibiotic (e.g., ampicillin) is transferred into E. coli cells, the host cells **become** ampicillin-resistant cells.
- So, if a recombinant DNA bearing gene for resistance to an antibiotic (e.g., ampicillin) is transferred into E. coli cells, the host cells **would become** ampicillin-resistant cells.
- So, if a recombinant DNA bearing gene for resistance to an antibiotic (e.g., ampicillin) is transferred into E. coli cells, the host cells **transform into** ampicillin-resistant cells.
- So, if a recombinant DNA bearing gene for resistance to an antibiotic (e.g., ampicillin) is transferred into E. coli cells, the host cells **would transform into** ampicillin-resistant cells.
- So, if a recombinant DNA bearing gene for resistance to an antibiotic (e.g., ampicillin) is transferred into E. coli cells, the host cells **will be transformed into** ampicillin-resistant cells.
- So, if a recombinant DNA bearing gene for resistance to an antibiotic (e.g., ampicillin) is transferred into E. coli cells, the host cells **would be transformed into** ampicillin-resistant cells.

This sentence is also correct.

- So, if a recombinant DNA bearing gene for resistance to an antibiotic (e.g., ampicillin) is transferred into E. coli cells, the host cells **become transformed** ampicillin-resistant cells.

Why?

Because in the last sentence, "transformed" is an adjective and is qualifying the noun phrase "ampicillin-resistant cells". In the previous sentences we were using either "one main verb" or "an auxiliary verb and a main verb". Auxiliary verbs are "be and its forms", "have and its forms" and a few others.

Why was your example sentence wrong?

Because it used two main verbs in sequence without intervening words or pauses (comma, semicolon, colon).